# Нет hyper-v, а очень надо. Что делать?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, hyper-v

Я хочу сделать приложение на xamarin forms. Однако при тесте приложения мне приходиться ждать, в прямом смысле, минут 5,чтобы оно запустилось. Visual studio предлагает мне включить hyper-v для ускорения эмуляции. Ну я начал искать, как это сделать, после чего выяснилось, что у меня его просто нет. Что делать? Скажите пожалуйста, я не хочу тратить в 10 раз больше времени на разработку по сравнению с нормальными условиями.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какой у вас процессор? Он поддерживает виртуализацию?

Comment: Смените windows home на pro

Comment: intel Core i5-3230M. Про виртуализацию не знаю.

Comment: Проверяйте [требования](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/reference/hyper-v-requirements), смотрите что у вас не подходит. Пробуйте [другие способы](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v) установки, если уверены, что ваш компьютер подходит под системные требования.

Comment: Как вариант подключить по USB мобильник, и отлаживать на нем свои программы. Предварительно в настройках телефона нужно зайти в раздел разработчика и включить отладку по USB. Если сравнивать отладку в эмуляторе с отладкой на реальном устройстве, то большой разницы  в скорости я не заметил.

Comment: Эмуляция чего? Андроида? | Не уверен, но можно попробовать запускать его в Docker.

Comment: если у вас процессор/система не поддерживает виртуализацию, то можно тестировать на реальном устройстве подключенном по usb

Comment: Проверьте, включена ли в BIOS опция Enable Virtualization. Еще если вызвать диспетчер задач, то на вкладке Производительность видно, включено или нет.

Comment: Я ещё раз посоветую посмотреть в сторону Докера. Он работает на домашней версии Винды без hyper-v. Беглый гуглёж показывает, что можно запускать в нём эмулятор Андроида и тем или иным образом работать с ним. Первоначальная настройка да, сложная. Но, _возможно_, в итоге это будет комфортней, чем сейчас.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эмуляция мобильного в любом случае дело далеко не из легковестных. Формально ты запускаешь вторую полноценную операционную систему в первой, да еще и эмулируя другую архитектуру процессора в придачу.

А с таким процессором в любом случае прийдется терпеть тормоза:

- процессор старый - дата выхода 01.01.2012
- процессор мобильного сегмента, а, значит, хуже работает априори
- процессор хуже охлаждается, а, значит, при нагрузке тротлится.
- твой проц бенчмаркается на 2521 бал. Что бы ты понимал - самый младший дешевый райзен которому уже 4 года имеет в 3 раза выше показатели. А современные процы нормального порядка уже в 10-20 раз мощнее. (5950X - 46000 балов)

---

Итак у тебя есть 3 выбора:

1. Пересесть на мак. Разработка под андроид наименее без тормозов и проблем идет под маком. Тем более, что последние маки имеют в себе ARM архитектуру процессора, что упрощает разработку для мобильных платформ еще в разы.
2. Купить стационарник с нормальным десктопным процессором вместо этого мобильного старья. И уже на него поставить операционку ядро которой поддерживает hyper-V. (windows 10 pro или выше). Про SSD тоже не забудь.
3. Вместо запуска на эмуляторе - запускать приложение непосредственно на телефоне для тестировки. И не издеваться над своим старым ноутбуком. **(это самый дешевый вариант, советую его)**

---

Пытаться же нормально и без тормозов разрабатывать на ноуте 10летней давности (еще и не самой мощной конфигурации) запуская на нем 2 операционки одновременно эмулируя процессор другой архитектуры, браузер да еще и IDE-шку - это издевательство над здравым смыслом.

Comment: У меня жена на ноуте 2008 года неплохо так играла в андройд игры на эмуляторе, но все тормозило. Я зашел в BIOS, а там нет опции включить виртуализацию, затем я пошел узнавать, поддерживает ли ее проц (старенький AMD), оказалось - поддерживает. Дальше я нашел как перепрошить BIOS так, чтобы опция появилась, так как она была заблокирована производителем. Прошил, опция появилась включл - и о чудо, эмулятор андройда просто начал летать по сравнению с тем, что было до этого. Так что здесь вопрос скорее технический, а не про то, как правильно выбросить старый комп. Но минус не мой.

Comment: @aepot только разовый запуск эмулятора и постоянные его запуски во время разработки - это разные вещи. Старт любой современной операционки в любом случае вещь весьма требовательная к ресурсам. Тем более что я посоветовал обратить внимание на пункт "запуск на телефоне" как самый дешевый вариант без выкидывания техники.